# Is Win32 Event object recursive mutexes?

Tags: windows, multithreading, locking, mutex, deadlock

I searched MSDN, Mutex could be locked twice, but there isn't any word on recursive acquire the same event object twice in the same thread.

can we lock the win32 events twice in the same thread?

**Edit**: what is the meaning of Lock events? here I assume event is auto-reset.

1. Lock:    a thread is waken up from  WaitForXXX (e.g. , WaitForSingleObject)
2. Un-Lock: a thread is calling SetEvent or PluseEvent.

Comment: Win32 events cannot be "locked". And what do you mean that a mutex can be locked twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mutex is fundamentally different to an event. Whereas a mutex is used to provide MUTual EXclusion, so that only one thread may access a resource at a time, an event is just a notification mechanism. An auto-reset event provides single-wakeup notifications, whereas a manual-reset event provides multiple-wakeup notifications.

If you signal an auto-reset event, only one thread will receive that signal, and that thread only once; any other threads --- or any other calls to a wait function for that event from the same thread --- will wait until there is a second call to `SetEvent`.

If you signal a manual-reset event then it stays signalled until you reset it, so multiple threads can wake, and multiple calls to a wait function for that event from the same thread will succeed until some thread calls `ResetEvent`.

An event doesn't have an "owner" either way: just because thread A was woken from its call to a wait function last time by another thread setting the event, there is nothing that prevents it waiting again, and nothing that specifies whether thread A or B will be woken if both wait on the same auto-reset event. There is also nothing that requires any particular thread to call `SetEvent`: any thread in the system may do so, whether or not that thread ever calls a wait function for that event. Indeed, a common use case has one thread calling `SetEvent`, and one or more other threads waiting.

So: yes, you can wait for an event from a thread that just waited for that event, but this is not a lock, and other threads may also wait for the event, and may also wake if the event is signalled.

**Update for edited question:**

You can **use** an event to provide a lock, but that is not part of the inherent semantics.  You may call `WaitForSingleObject` twice in succession using the same auto-reset event handle. This is not an error as far as Windows is concerned: you just need to ensure that some other thread or threads calls `SetEvent` twice, in such a way that the waiting thread wakes from the first call to `WaitForSingleObject` before the second call to `SetEvent` happens, in order to avoid "lost" wakeups: `SetEvent` doesn't count the calls, it just sets the flag.

Also: do not use `PulseEvent`. It does not guarantee that a thread will wake, even if there is one currently waiting.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Anthony Williams.

One note that I'd like to add is that many people (not just you) don't quite understand the difference between a mutex and an auto-reset event. They actually behave similarly and *may* (from the technical perspective) be used for resource locking.

The major difference between them is that mutex "knows" which thread holds it. That is, when `WaitForSingleObject` (or similar) acquires a mutex - it's automatically "assigned" to the calling thread. This has two consequences:

1. Mutex may be acquired recursively by the same thread. This won't work with an auto-reset event of course.
2. If the thread owning a mutex exits - the mutex is automatically "freed". The appropriate `WaitXXXX` function will return with `WAIT_ABANDONED`.

Events OTOH may be seen as particular cases of semaphores. Auto-reset event is equivalent to a semaphore charged by (at most) 1, and manual-reset event - equivalent to an infinitely-charged semaphore.